# How to connect to a website with proxy python

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

The code I tried gives no errors but it prints my ip instead of the proxy.

```
import requests
proxies = {
    "https://": "51.79.145.108:3128",
    "http://": "51.79.145.108:3128"
}
url="https://httpbin.org/ip"
r=requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
ip=r.json()
print(ip)
```

Comment: some proxies doesn't hide your IP.

Comment: it should be `"http"`, `"https"` without `://`. But this proxy doesn't work. Many free proxies are closed and they don't work. You could try to install `Tor` to use `Tor Network` for proxy

Comment: Or you should register on portal like [windscribe](https://windscribe.com/yo/kez9ypcg) or[ScraperAPI](https://www.scraperapi.com/?fp_ref=dhxwo) to get free and tested proxies but some limit every month.